# Why is the word "misadventure" not "misventure"?

Tags: meaning

I came across a news article mentioning a coroner's diagnosis of death as "death by *misadventure*". And I wondered what the word **misadventure** actually meant.

Here's the [dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misadventure) :

> **misadventure** [ˌmɪsədˈvɛntʃə] n
>
> 1. an unlucky event; misfortune
> 2. (Law) Law accidental death not due to crime or negligence

This surprised me, as I would have expected it to essentially mean "an **adventure** that went wrong". That doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to mean "an incident that went wrong". So wouldn't it make more sense for the word to be **mis-venture**?

Why is this not the case?

Comment: Because we generally associate the noun _venture_ with financial risk, as in _venture capital_ and a _business venture_, and just because the legal definition is old, from Middle English and Old French.

Comment: @BillFranke I doubt Baden-Powell was thinking of financial risk when he formed the Venture Scouts. I suspect he wanted to introduce older teenagers to novel and exciting things. And yes, I just realised how bad those sentences could sound juxtaposed.

Comment: I think the term "venture capital" and the financial implications of "venture" were not in prevalence when the word misadventure came into existence. Therefore, saying that "misadventure" is used rather than "misventure" due to financial implications is hmmm ... unacceptable opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=misadventure&searchmode=none) can help here.

> **Misadventure**
>   late 13c., *misaventure,* from O.Fr. *mesaventure* (12c.) "accident, mishap," from *mesavenir* "to turn out badly;" see **mis-** (2) + **adventure** (n.).
>
> **mis-**
>   in *mischief, miscreant,* etc., represents O.Fr. *mes-* "bad, badly, wrong, wrongly," from V.L. *minus-,* from L. *minus* "less", which was not used as a prefix.
>
> **adventure**
>   c.1200, *auenture* "that which happens by chance, fortune, luck," from Old French *aventure* (11c.) "chance, accident, occurrence, event, happening," from Latin *adventura (res)* "(a thing) about to happen," from *adventurus,* future participle of *advenire* "to come to, reach, arrive at," from *ad-* "to" + *venire* "to come".

Thus *misadventure* means "by accident having done something which turned out badly". It's a remarkably concise and exact word and ideally suited to coroners' verdicts.

The *-adventure* part of *misadventure* doesn't mean the *Boy's Own* stuff of an "exciting undertaking", also mentioned by Etymonline. That meaning took three hundred years to evolve from the earlier use of *adventure* mentioned above.

> Meaning developed through "risk/danger" (a trial of one's chances), c.1300, and "perilous undertaking" (late 14c.) and thence to "a novel or exciting incident" (1560s). Earlier it also meant "a wonder, a miracle; accounts of marvelous things" (13c.). The -d- was restored 15c.-16c. *Venture* is a 15c. variant.